# Laravel Upload Image and generate random name for image

Tags: php, laravel

**I am new in laravel**, can you help me to upload image and generate random names for the image via query bulder? and this mycode thanks before

```php
public function AddEvents(Request $request){
    DB::table('events')->insert([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'image' => $request->image,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'time'=>$request->time
        ]);
   return redirect('/');     
}`
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to ask an at least halfway specific question here - “can you help me” is not that.

Comment: Do you just want to generate random names?

Comment: simply use https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem  laravel filesystem you will get random name for file that will be stored in db

Comment: yes, I just need to generate a random name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function AddEvents(Request $request){
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'image' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif|max:1024',
        ]);

        $image= $request->file('image');
        $file_upload = false;
        $destinationPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image'; // make sure to create this directry in public_html (Apache, Cpanel) OR public (nginx)
       if($image && $image->isValid()){
            $fileName = md5(microtime()).'_'.$request->name;
            $image->move($destinationPath, $fileName.'.jpeg');
            $file_upload = true;
        }
try {
    DB::table('events')->insert([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'image' => $fileName,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'time'=>$request->time
        ]);
return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Added Successfully.');
} catch (\Exception $e){
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }    
}
```